# How to add a button to enable background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a background.js file which can intercept the web requests and replace the value of `User-Agent` header. It works fine as per the below manifest.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "TamperHeaders",
  "description": "Replace HTTP headers and parameters",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "38.png"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

I want to add a `default_popup` and add a button to that popup, say "Click me!", and upon clicking on the button, the extension should get activated (i.e.,the background.js should start to run). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) allows your extension to communicate between different contexts. Such as background scripts, content scripts and popups.

To achieve what you're wanting to do you'd need to send a message from the popup when the button is click, to your background script to register your chrome.webRequest listener. For example:

popup.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="my-button">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('my-button');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'STARTLISTENER'});
        window.close(); // Closes the popup
    });
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.action == 'STARTLISTENER') {
            chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
                // web request logic
            };
        }
    }
)
```

As well as these changes your [manifest would need updating to include popup.html](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups).

Note, due to the content security policy [you can't use `<script>` tags inline](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2#inline_scripts) within the HTML. Hence the separate popup.html and popup.js files.

Comment: `addEventListener` was the trick. This exactly solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are saying

> I want to add a default_popup and add a button to that popup, say "Click me!", and upon clicking on the button, the extension should get activated

It seems you don't need a popup at all. Just use [Browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) and when the user clicks the 'icon'(browser action), you logic code will be executed.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    // you logic here
});
```

Comment: This is cool. But sometimes I may want to add more functionalities which may required to be added as buttons in my default popup.